# How do they commercially coat gummies in wax?

Tags: gelatin

I've been making gummies very successfully for a couple years and just coating them in citric acid/sugar before i dry them, which works well, but im curious how i can make them shiny like haribo gummies. I know they use carnuaba wax or something, and i assume they tumble them in a giant tumbler, but how do they dissolve and atomize the wax? How do they keep them from sticking in the tumbler before they get coated? Obviously you can't heat them so the wax must be dissolved in some solvent? If anyone knows these secrets I would love to hear them!

Answer (score 2):

The tumbler does a really good job of making sure the gummies get coated.

It will mist in the wax and definitely get it everywhere. 
You can see on the gummies where they were sorta stuck together, some still come stuck together.

So the waxing isn't quite perfect but most of them come free.

Comment: How it's made has an episode about gummy candy which is available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzOQZsNkYMs).